# what does curlopt_binarytranfer exactly mean?

Tags: php, libcurl

i dont understand what is the difference between

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER AND
CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER
```

i wrote a script to check it

```
<?php
$image_url = "http://localhost/curl/img1.png";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$image = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $image;
?>
```

in this case i get the image displayed in the browser 
if i remove the line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
```

i still get the image displayed in the browser.

and now if i remove the line

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

then iget binary data display in browser(looks like garbage) in both cases whether i remove
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
or i dont remove.
then what difference does this option `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` make?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER isn't used by PHP anymore, if I am understanding this PHP bug report and resolution correctly.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55635

Comment: You're understanding it correctly, the [NEWS file diff](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blobdiff;f=NEWS;h=7028faf2500381b61bada2c9f1ac50c4a25339c5;hp=2e83f29921f180ae55382f061e1fd48a1a664626;hb=33d3eb1e43134deb3e108108f62febdabc8a0aa1;hpb=aeaa4b3da6261b87bae2f80b8507f9081ca4cd55) in the commit says "CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER no longer used. The constant still exists for backward compatibility but is doing nothing"

Answer (score 4):

With this kind of curl we are looking at *two* transfers:

1. data travels from the target host to our PHP host
2. it is sent from our PHP host to our browser.

By removing `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` you deny the browser the clue as to how the content that follows should be interpreted. This has nothing to do with `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` which affects the first transfer.

Comment: then what effect can CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER make? can you give an example?

Comment: something i could understand from your link is that people have tried a lot more things in understanding CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER.

Comment: @lovesh, True. It is actually required for PHP's sake, so it knows how to treat the returned result. But the responsibility is placed on curl. So, basically, PHP is telling curl: *whenever you are about to fetch binary data, tell me so I don't mess it*. But, PHP's intelligence and sophistication in figuring out, on its own, if the returned data should be treated as binary or text has fluctuated over time (some releases have introduced bugs worsening it, and some improved it). So, with some builds you can get the result without using the option. But to be safe you'd better always warn PHP.