# Curl request with headers - separate body a from a header

Tags: php

Ive got a code

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Now i want to extract the body from $ret without headers. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about this:

```
list($headers, $content) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $ret, 2);
```

... which should give you the body of your request in the $content variable?

Comment: This fails when HTTP/1.1. 100 Continue headers exist.

Comment: You can remove the Continue-Header with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));`.

Comment: This is also invalid when CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is used and an address with a 301 or 302 redirect is fetched.

Comment: This is solid for GET requests, but for situations like POST, see natiupiru's answer.

Comment: damn that 100 Continue gotcha cost me the better part of the day!

Answer (score 44):

raina77ow's response is good. From the comments it looks like there are a few conditions that would cause the "explode" to not work. I found a way that works better for me and thought I'd share.

By calling curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE) you can get the length of the response header. So I did the following:

```
// Original Code
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
$responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Added Code
$header_len = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($ret, 0, $header_len);
$body = substr($ret, $header_len);

// Back to Original Code
curl_close($ch);
```

This is working great for me. I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: It seems `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` doesn't do anything anymore. [see this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007363/what-does-curlopt-binarytranfer-exactly-mean)

Comment: Perfect answer... at last I'm saved from those bad scripts that just split by '\n\n'

Answer (score 2):

*Drawing on @Geoffrey excellent answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135574/195835)...*

Some of the other solutions offered this thread are *not* doing this correctly.

- Splitting on `\r\n\r\n` is not reliable when `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is on or when the server responds with a 100 code.
- Detecting the size of the headers via `CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE` is also not always reliable, especially when proxies are used or in some of the same redirection scenarios.

**The most reliable method of obtaining headers is using [`CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html).** Then you can remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` and your body will be clean with no headers.

Here is a very clean method of performing this using PHP closures. It also converts all headers to lowercase for consistent handling across servers and HTTP versions.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = [];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Run the following function for each header received
// Note: Does NOT handle multiple instances of the same header. Later one will overwrite.
//       Consider handling that scenario if you need it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($curl, $header) use (&$headers) {
    $len = strlen($header);
    $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
    if (count($header) >= 2)
        $headers[strtolower(trim($header[0]))] = trim($header[1]);
    return $len;
});

$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($headers);
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such. If not, tailor the answer to this specific question.

Comment: This works great.

Comment: Best answer I found. Thanks